# Are S3 500 internal error retries necessary when using aws client?

Tags: amazon-s3

I've read that you should retry 500 internal errors with S3, but I also read that the client handles things like retries (defaults to 10), retry interval, circuitbreaker, etc. Are explicit retries necessary when using the aws client?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the answer is no. The AWS SDK handles retries fairly robustly.